# Google Maps plugin: API error

Tags: google-maps-for-ee, google-maps, api

I've got a long running EE install that uses the old Google Map plugin.

Lately though, we've been seeing this error in the CP

```
you have exceeded your daily request quota for this API
```

I've seen one other dev see similar - wonder if anyone else has and has a fix?

Answer (score 0):

If seems like you have exceeding the free **(Free until exceeding 25,000 map loads per 24 hours)** [usage limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage), now you need to go for [Premium Plan](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage).

Comment: I doubt that very much